# Switch wAny hAny to wCompact hRegular cause issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am using storyboard and as I say in all my question it is a pain in my head.

When I switched form the wAny hAny in storyboard to wCompact hRegular some my element that I use for any width and any hight were changed and storyboard shown issue with constraints. I have no words... I don't know how storyboard update it without me. The issue happened with collection views.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question there. You need to show what constraints you have and what issues are reported. What views and constraints do you have which are only installed in some classes?

Comment: @Wain, it's just appear randomly, seems like a bug in storyboard. It's not connected to constraint. There is no constraint for wCompact hRegular, only for wAny hAny size class. But when I switch it to wC hR it cause some resizing.